# No overload matches this call Error on TSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-proptypes

I am new to React and TypeScript.

I passed the propTypes into a styled-component and it showed me this error:

> No overload matches this call.
>
> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { order: Order; client: Client; orderDetail: OrderDetails; confirmation: Confirmation; shipping: Shipping; payment: Payment; ... 255 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...>; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
>
> Type '{ children: Element[]; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ order: Order; client: Client; orderDetail: OrderDetails; confirmation: Confirmation; shipping: Shipping; payment: Payment; ... 255 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...>; }': order, client, orderDetail, confirmation, and 2 more.
>
> Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", any, OrderCardProps, never, "div", "div">): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", any, OrderCardProps, never, "div", "div">, string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>', gave the following error.
>
> Type '{ children: Element[]; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ order: Order; client: Client;....255 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...>; }': order, client, orderDetail, confirmation, and 2 more.ts(2769)

styles.ts

```
export const StatusLayout = styled.div<OrderCardProps>`
display: flex;
> div {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: auto 2px;
```

componant.tsx

```
export interface OrderCardProps {
order: Order
client: Client
orderDetail: OrderDetails
confirmation: Confirmation
shipping: Shipping
payment: Payment
}

export const OrderCard: React.FC<OrderCardProps> = ({ order, ...}) => { return ( ....
...
...
<StatusLayout>
    <div>
        <Icon size={"l"} color={colors.blueDark3} children={<MdPermPhoneMsg/>}/>
    </div>
```

The ERROR is in `<StatusLayout>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that you call your `<StatusLayout>` component but without the mandatory props that you declared in its definition `const StatusLayout = styled.div<OrderCardProps>`

For example you could call it like:

```
<StatusLayout
  order={myOrder}
  client={someClient}
  orderDetail={myOrderDetail}
  confirmation={someConfirmation}
  shipping={theShipping}
  payment={andThePayment}
>
  // children...
</StatusLayout>
```

That being said, since `<StatusLayout>` is just a styled div, all these props can only be used in the style definition (because styled-components will not pass them to the div), which is unlikely, so it is questionable why you need them.